# Ortools - Set MPVariable as MPConstrains bound

Tags: c++, or-tools

I'd like to do something like:

```cpp
namespace opr = operations_research;
double min = 10;
opr::MPVariable* const y1 = solver.MakeBoolVar("y1");
opr::MPConstraint *const c1 = solver.MakeRowConstraint(-min * y1, 10);
```

but the compiler complains because of incompatible data types, dereferencing the pointer doesn't work either and the only way to compile it is by using `y1->solution_value()` but I don't think that's the correct solution because it copies the current y1 value and I'd like the bound to change with y1.
For context, `y1` is a flag variable for when a certain condition on other variables is met.
The type of constraint I'm trying to write is something like:

`-M * y_1 <= x <= 10`

Comment: Just add two constraints

Comment: @LaurentPerron what do you mean? The issue here is not the 2 equations but the fact that I can't use the MPVariable inside the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

As @LaurentPerron mentioned in the comment the solution is simply to rewrite the constraint so that the bounds are numbers and not MPVariable.
For the example I posted it'd be like:

`-M * y_1 <= x <= 10`

Write it as:

```
x <= 10
x + M * y1 >= 0
```